# Data uploading through a website

Tags: php, drupal

I am creating website where a user should upload an ASCII file from his computer. The file can be pretty big, let's say, 50-100 Mb. Should I use a ftp or the server for that? Does Drupal or PHP have a corresponded module?

Comment: What reliability are you expecting for the upload?  Will the user's connection be generally stable?

Answer (score 1):

To get the file off the client using PHP you are looking at HTTP.  PHP's [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) functions won't help with that.  Is FTP preferred for transporting large files?  Yes, the name says it all.  You should be able to use PHP to POST files 50-100 Mb in size pretty solidly.  If you do run into problems they will probably be in scalability, a few long running uploads on a pre-fork mod_php install can exhaust your connections pretty quick.

Comment: Suppose we should also mention [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/).

Answer (score 0):

FTP is too complicated for most users.  You can do this in PHP but you will need to turn up the max post size to allow you to upload files that are so big

### In .htaccess:

php_value upload_max_filesize    110M

### php_value post_max_size          120M

The only problem with this is it opens you up to denial-of-service attacks (someone can slowly upload large files to keep your server busy, and you can't block it in PHP because the PHP script doesn't start until the file upload is complete)

Comment: Will probably need to adjust the following in .htacess:
`upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_input_time, php_value max_execution_time`
As Robert point sout these are not good php.ini defaults.  Using `ini_set()` on the script wont't work since a couple of those are PHP_INI_PERDIR.